# Create asset in Magnolia programmatically

Tags: spring, file-upload, magnolia

We're developing a Magnolia Blossom / Spring app where the *end user* needs to upload an image at some point. So we're considering storing these images as assets in Magnolia.

However, with the uploaded MultipartFile ready at the Spring controller level, I haven't yet found a successful way to store the uploaded image into a Magnolia asset.

I imagine there should be some easier way to *programmatically* (i.e. Java code) create an asset in Magnolia when, for example, by some means, you have just the bytes of a PNG / JPEG.

Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from the [Magnolia forum](https://forum.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=8a22aaec-21e8-487a-b0ee-319409bd4fdb) here's what I got to:

```
private void saveImageAsEventAsset(final MultipartFile multipartFile, final ImageInfo imageInfo, final String prefix) {
        MgnlContext.doInSystemContext(
                new MgnlContext.VoidOp() {
                    @Override
                    public void doExec() {
                        try {
                            String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                            String newFileName = prefix + "_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "." + fileExtension;

                            // "Navigate" to the assets folder node
                            AssetProviderRegistry assetProviderRegistry = Components.getComponent(AssetProviderRegistry.class);
                            JcrAssetProvider jcrAssetProvider = (JcrAssetProvider) assetProviderRegistry.getProviderById(DamConstants.DEFAULT_JCR_PROVIDER_ID);
                            JcrFolder assetFolder = (JcrFolder) jcrAssetProvider.getFolder("/event");
                            Node assetFolderNode = assetFolder.getNode();

                            // Create asset node
                            Node assetNode = JcrUtils.getOrAddNode(assetFolderNode, newFileName, AssetNodeTypes.Asset.NAME);
                            assetNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.Asset.ASSET_NAME, newFileName);

                            Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession(DamConstants.WORKSPACE);

                            // Create asset resource node
                            Node assetResourceNode = JcrUtils.getOrAddNode(assetNode, AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.RESOURCE_NAME, AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.NAME);
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.DATA, session.getValueFactory().createBinary(multipartFile.getInputStream()));
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.FILENAME, newFileName);
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.EXTENSION, fileExtension);
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.SIZE, Long.toString(multipartFile.getSize()));
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.MIMETYPE, imageInfo.getMimeType());
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.WIDTH, Long.toString(imageInfo.getWidth()));
                            assetResourceNode.setProperty(AssetNodeTypes.AssetResource.HEIGHT, Long.toString(imageInfo.getHeight()));

                            session.save();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.debug("Could not save image as event asset", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

where the org.devlib.schmidt.imageinfo.**ImageInfo** parameter comes from a previous validation that the uploaded **MultipartFile** is an image and the prefix String is just something we needed in the asset name.